# std::allocator not preserving old allocated items after reallocation

Tags: c++, allocator

I am trying to realize a Vector class that allocates a block of memory, and eventually re-allocate it if it needs to contain more items.
I am using std::allocator to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Vector
{
private:
    T* data;
    allocator<T> data_all;
    int length;
    int _size;
    static const int block_size=10;
    void init()
    {
        length=0;
        _size=block_size;
        data=data_all.allocate(block_size,NULL);
    }
public:
    Vector()
    {
        init();
    }
    int size() const
    {
        return length;
    }
    void push_back(T item)
    {
        length++;
        if(length > _size)
        {
            _size+=block_size;
            data=data_all.allocate(_size,data);
        }
        data_all.construct(&data[length-1],item);
    }
    T& operator[] (int i)
    {
        if(i<0 || i>= length)
            throw out_of_range("The index is out of vector range");
        return data[i];
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Vector<int> v;
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        v.push_back(i);
    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
        cout << v[i] << "\t";
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the item previously allocated are not preserved, it prints:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
```

Instead of:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
```

Why this behaviour? Isn't there a way in C++ to re-allocate contiguous items like in C with realloc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `allocate` is just a hint that the allocator *could* use to try and return new memory close to the old memory, but is ignored by `std::allocator` and fairly useless for vector-like containers because all the elements are close to each other anyway, as they're in a contiguous block.

You seem to be expecting it to copy the existing data. It won't. You have to do that, by copying from the old memory block to the new one.

You're also leaking the old memory.  You need to deallocate it.

You want something like:

```
void push_back(const T& item)
{
    if (length == _size)
    {
        T* new_data = data_all.allocate(_size+block_size);
        // N.B. if any of the following copies throws new_data will be leaked
        std::uninitialized_copy(data, data+length, new_data);
        std::destroy(data, data+length);
        data_all.deallocate(data, _size);
        data = new_data;
        _size+=block_size;
    }
    data_all.construct(&data[length++],item);
}
```

Comment: Isn't there an alternative way, that at least TRIES to allocate the new block in a contiguous position (like realloc in C) ?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer:  `realloc` only has to deal with raw, uninitialized memory, a block of memory in a C++ vector will contain initialized objects that need to be destroyed by running a destructor, it's far more complicated, especially if you need to ensure exceptions-safety.

Comment: Since `std::allocator::allocate` returns uninitialized memory, I think you want to use [`std::uninitialized_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy) instead of `std::copy` in your `push_back` example.

Comment: To increase performace, I think I'll use malloc and realloc, to allocate pointers and every pointer will be initialized with new.